# How do you include the contents of another cell in the coding of a cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

A cell in a Table content is

```
=COUNTIFS([DECK NBI YR 7],[@[DECK NBI YR 7]],[PRELIM REHAB CANDIDATE YR 7],"Yes")
```

I want to link the first two terms to other cells that will contain the text for these arguments.

`[@Name1]` is a cell in the Table and contains the text `[DECK NBI YR 7]`
and `[@Name2]` contains `[@[DECK NBI YR 7]]`

The contents of cells `@Name1` and `@Name2` vary and I want to use them as arguments in the equation of another cell in the same table.

The following code does not work:

```
COUNTIFS([@Name1],[@Name2],[PRELIM REHAB CANDIDATE YR 7]," Yes ")
```

---

I want:

```
COUNTIFS([@Name1],[@Name2],[PRELIM REHAB CANDIDATE YR 7]," Yes ")
```

to become:

```
=COUNTIFS([DECK NBI YR 7],[@[DECK NBI YR 7]],[PRELIM REHAB CANDIDATE YR 7],"Yes")
```

---

I tried `=countifs(indirect([@Name1]), ...`
That gives an `#N/A` error.

I tried to use `=countifs(value([@Names1]), ...`

I also tried `=countifs(contents([@Name1]), ...`

I tried `=countifs(""&[@Name1]&"", ...`

Comment: Post few sample data then show your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work if you just use "DECK NBI YR 7" in the Name1 and Name2 columns. Leave the [@[]] characters in the INDIRECT formula.

Include the table name in the INDIRECT formula.

The below works for a table named Table1. You will need to change it to match your table name:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("Table1["&[@Name1]&"]"),INDIRECT("Table1[@["&[@Name2]&"]]"),[PRELIM REHAB CANDIDATE YR 7],"Yes")
```

Comment: Thank you very much Kevin, I really appreciate your help!  (It works now).  